# Tweepy - is it possible to stream exact phrases?

Tags: python, tweepy

```
TheStreamer.filter(languages=["en"], track=['Bruno Mars is lovely'])
```

Is there a way to get this to track an exact phrase, rather than relevant phrases? For instance,

> 'Bruno Mars really is a lovely man'

would probably be a result, which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

As per [the documentation for `track`](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/filter-realtime/guides/basic-stream-parameters)

> Exact matching of phrases (equivalent to quoted phrases in most search engines) is not supported.

So the simple answer is no, you cannot prevent matching tweets in which all words are present in any order and with any punctuation with this technique. You're going to have to filter out results that don't match your criteria after the fact.