# How to filter twitter with blank between characters?

Tags: python, nlp, web-crawler, tweepy, twitter-streaming-api

based on twitter streaming api [track](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters#track) and tweepy, I'd like to filter twitter posts contains
 "A  B" with code below:

```
twitter_stream.filter(track=['A B'])
```

But the result are not expected:

```
A New Project Featuring ASAP Rocky Vince Staples Lil B
In a contract, A &amp; B agree to do various
```

But what I want to match as below:

```
A B want to .... 
...xx A B xx...
```

Anybody have these experiences ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36645685/tweepy-is-it-possible-to-stream-exact-phrases You can write a function to validate the tweets yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Encode space to '%20'.

```
twitter_stream.filter(track=['A%20B'])
```